# Android.FirebaseUI: Change translated text to device's language?

Tags: android, firebaseui

Android 2.3.3

I use **FirebaseUI-Android** and it's work fine.

[FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

But I found problem.
In my application I select application language (not equal to device language).Suppose device language is **English**. But application language is **Spain**.

When open screen for enter phone number (or second screen for enter SMS), the text is on **Spain**. OK. But when I rotate screen the text translate to device language (in example is English).

How I can fix this?

Comment: probably set the locale in onResume of the activity?

Comment: What is the name of this FirebaseUI activity?